# Datadiff, output of the diff not consistent

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, diff, static-libraries

I trying to use a library: [Datadiff](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/datadiff) but the output of the diff seems to be not consistent. I'm analysing two json, making some dictionary out of them and then i'm comparing the dictionaries. But for the first file the output shows all the objects changed, while in the second file the output is in lines, so the lines of the json which are not the same are showed but not the whole object that changed remains a mistery in the diff. I'm quite confused by this behaviour, can you explain me or solve this problem? Below is the code:

```
    out = datadiff.diff(t[0].get("key"),t[1].get("key"))
    if options.get("key2") != None:
        out = scorecheck(out,options.get("key2"))
    if checkdiff(str(out)):
        f.write("Feelings:<br/>")
        printdiff(f, str(out))
```

The output from the diff of the first file:

```
+{u'origin': u'VIRTUAL', u'score': 1, u'type': u'PLACES', u'name': u'comune di Roma'},
+{u'origin': u'VIRTUAL', u'score': 1, u'type': u'PLACES', u'name': u'provincia di Roma'},
```

Diff from the second file:

```
 -u'position': 1,:
  u'score': 1,:
  u'score': 1,:
  u'score': 1,:
```

I'm trying to select all the "object" which contain score 1, not only the lines that say score 1 in the json. So the first output for me is ok, the second is useless.

Comment: Can you show us an example of first and second file?

Comment: Datadiff appears to work only on Python structures, not on files. So I don't understand what your file formats have to do with it. You should look at your dictionaries instead.

Comment: The files are very different from each other, i had to use two dictionaries to contain the data stored in the json in an ordered manner. It is easier then making the diff of the two files and reading it.

Answer (score 0):

Datadiff is not the sacred book of diffs, especially for python structures diff. You can build the function you prefer to make the diff you need, personalized, and it's very easy to do so. There are many examples on this site. Many people prefer to build a diff by new instead of using the datadiff library (which is even not very well documented).
So below is an example of code to make the diff of two list of dict. It returns a list of list of dict, the first contains the diff from the first file, the second the diff of the second file compared. It is useful to print in a html file the two list in different color:

```
def listdiff(listofdict1,listofdict2):
listofdict3 = []
listofdict4 = []
for i in listofdict1:
    if i not in listofdict2:
        listofdict3.append(i)
for j in listofdict2:
    if j not in listofdict1:
        listofdict4.append(j)
return [listofdict3,listofdict4]
```